# Laravel Fakers Factories

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I try fill the table with laravels factories, default UserFactory.php work well. 
But my project has a several custom services connect with composer and located above main app folder. Models, Controllers, Requests and other lara tool work, migrations work with seeders, but when I want use Fakers I get error:
1. when I use `factory(Model::class, 150)->create()` in tinker

```
InvalidArgumentException with message 'Unable to locate factory with name [default]
```

2. when I run db:seed

```
Unable to locate factory with name [default]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Laravel Factory Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/database-testing#creating-models):

Try using

```
factory(\Vpn\Services\Payment\Models\Request\User::class, 150)->create();
```

or import using

```
use Vpn\Services\Payment\Models\Request\User;

factory(User::class, 150)->create();
```

or try using

```
factory('\Vpn\Services\Payment\Models\Request\User', 150)->create();
```

Comment: Can you provide me the namespace of the Model

Comment: [Vpn/Services/Payment/Models/Request/User] for example

Comment: Did you create the model factory as above namespace?